# Can't get If-Statement to work correct in Jinja using List of Integers

Tags: python, html, flask, jinja2

I can't get my if statement to trigger correctly.
If I change it to if controller in [1,2], then it will change my first 2 buttons to green.

But when I try to use this list of integers, I can't seem to get it to work. I even print the list to my terminal before sending it and ensure it is list of integers (not strings) and it is.
*list index of finished controllers (print statement result):
[1, 2]*

Also the values are showing up in my url such as 'list_index_of_finished_controllers=1&list_index_of_finished_controllers=2', Which seems right to me so I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

'''

```
<!-- CONTROLLERS ON LEFT SIDE OF PAGE -->
    <div class="row col-md-2">
        <div class="content-section">
            <form method="POST" action="">
                {{ form.csrf_token() }}
                <div class="btn-toolbar" role="toolbar" aria-label="Toolbar with button groups">
                    <div class="btn-group-vertical mr-2" role="group" aria-label="First group">
                    {% for controller in range(1, sales_order_controller_quantity+1) %}               
                    {%- if controller in list_index_finished_controllers -%}
                        <input type='submit' class="btn btn-success" name='controller{{controller}}' value="{{ tag_prefix }} {{ controller }}"></input>
                    {% elif controller == current_controller %}
                        <input type='submit' class="btn btn-primary" name='controller{{controller}}' value="{{ tag_prefix }} {{ controller }}"></input>
                    {% else %}
                        <input type='submit' class="btn btn-secondary" name='controller{{controller}}' value="{{ tag_prefix }} {{ controller }}"></input>
                    {% endif %}                      
                    {% endfor %}
                    </div>
                        
                </div> 
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
```

'''

Comment: {%- why you put the - after {%

Comment: @NavaneethaKrishnan I inserted that after reading it would remove empty lines, I thought it might help. My logic doesn't work whether I have the hyphens or not. 
It works for making the current controller button color blue (primary), and all my other buttons grey (secondary), but fails to make any buttons Green, unless I hard code the list such as I explained in my question.

Answer (score 0):

I'm still learning flask, but I think I can help you a bit.

You should not add the `-` after `{%` but before `%}` in if statements,

also, `{# #}` is used for jinja2 comments instead of `<!-- -->`.

For example:

```
{% if controller in list_index_finished_controllers -%}
    {# --snip-- #}
{% elif controller == current_controller -%}
    {# --snip-- #}
{% else -%}
    {# --snip-- #}
{%- endif %} {# add the - after {% in {% end** %} blocks #}
```

or if you want to delete **ALL** blank lines automatically generated by jinja2, you can add this in your python code instead of add `-`:

```
app.jinja_env.trim_blocks = True
app.jinja_env.lstrip_blocks = True
```

Note that the python code above doesn't work with jinja2 macros.

Comment: Thanks for trying to help Andy. I added these hyphens in an attempt to fix issue but it doesn't work with or without hyphens.

Oh wow I just finally found solution. 
It was a typo... :(
My variable name should have been 'list_index_of_finished_controllers', I was skipped the '_of_' part in my jinja syntax. Now it's working as expected! 
View result here->
https://pasteboard.co/JxrJtmZ.png